# Is there an official and public pool of miners/"stakers" participating in the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: proof-of-stake, mining-pools

With the last discussion about PoW vs PoS, Ethereum planning migrating to pure PoS (Casper), new actors in the scene (EOS)...I have digged into this PoS, pros and cons against PoW.

One of the things that **I could not find is a list/pie of validators**, as I can find for the Bitcoin blockchain (https://www.blockchain.com/pools).

Does exist such a thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no list of current validators as we haven't moved to PoS yet.

If you want a graphical representation of the top *miners*, have a look at the following pie chart: https://etherscan.io/stat/miner?range=7&blocktype=blocks

These may or may not be pools. (I'm suspecting they all are, but there's no actual way to tell, other than from the name.)